# In Gensim Word2vec, how to reduce the vocab size of an existing model?

Tags: gensim, word2vec, vocabulary

In Gensims word2vec api, I trained a model where I initialized the model with max_final_vocab = 100000 and saved the model using model.save()
(This gives me one .model file, one .model.trainables.syn1neg.npy and one .model.wv.vectors.npy file).

I do not need to train model any further, so I'm fine with using just

```py
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load("train.fr.model")
kv = model.wv
del model
```

the kv variable shown here. I now want to use only the *top* N (N=40000 in my case) vocabulary items instead of the entire vocabulary. The only way to even attempt cutting down the vocabulary I could find was

```py
import numpy as np
emb_matrix = np.load("train.fr.model.wv.vectors.npy")
emb_matrix.shape
# (100000, 300)
new_emb_matrix = emb_matrix[:40000]
np.save("train.fr.model.wv.vectors.npy", new_emb_matrix)
```

If I load this model again though, the vocabulary still has length 100000.

I want to reduce the vocabulary of the model or model.wv while retaining a working model. Retraining is not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors

model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('train.fr.model', limit=1000)
```

Use optional `limit`parameter to reduce number of vectors that will be loaded from **Word2Vec** model file.